# Children on alien planet emerge from stasis/virtual reality early due to fire; group has to fight against hostile and manipulative computer

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book within the last 5 years and I think it was published within the last decade or so.

A group of children (teenagers mostly) are being "grown" in some facility controlled by an AI, which IIRC has them in virtual reality programs for training purposes (sort of like in *Idlewild*). They emerge early due to a catastrophic fire breaking out and have to quickly form a society.

It turns out the computer has gone insane, and it's manipulating the leaders that emerge to do what it wants. One group rebels and manages to overthrow the computer and the human leadership.

I think there's also a very tall tree canopy with these giant worms that travel up and down the trunk and into the canopy, but that may be from another book.